# CoovaChilli 1.3.0 configuration error --with curl was given, but test for curl failed

Tags: ubuntu, curl, coovachilli

Trying to configure CoovaChilli 1.3.0 with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=\$${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\$${prefix}/share/info \--sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-largelimits \--enable-binstatusfile --enable-statusfile --enable-chilliproxy \--enable-chilliradsec --enable-chilliredir --with-openssl --with-curl \--with-poll --enable-dhcpopt --enable-sessgarden --enable-dnslog \--enable-ipwhitelist --enable-redirnsreq --enable-miniconfig \--enable-libjson --enable-layer3 --enable-proxyvsa --enable-miniportal \--enable-modules --enable-multiroot
```

I encounter with the following error :

```
checking for curl_global_init in -lcurl... no
configure: error: in `/home/reaper/chilli/coova-chilli-1.3.0':
configure: error: --with-curl was given, but test for curl failed
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have provided the    config.log file [here](https://pastebin.com/kS5Yj5ks)

Comment: Config.log file hasn't been provided.

Comment: I have provided it now.

Comment: This bug is reported here: [Compilation error with --with-curl #396](https://github.com/coova/coova-chilli/issues/396)

Comment: Yes I checked it but there was no solution.